# updating pointer in array doesn't update the original pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a ball that has 1 adjacent ball as shown in the code below. The problem I am facing is updating the ball 2 value which is stored in ball1 's adjacent, doesn't update the actual ball 2.

```
    struct ball {
      struct ball * adjacent;
      size_t n_adjacent;
    };


    // Setting ball 2
    struct ball ball2 = { .n_adjacent= 0, .adjacent = NULL } ;


    // setting ball 1
    struct ball ball1 =  { .n_adjacent= 1, .adjacent = NULL } ;

    // setting ball 1's adjacent 
    struct ball * ball1_adj = (struct ball*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct ball));
    ball1_adj[0] = ball2;

    ball1.adjacent = ball1_adj;

    printf("Address of original ball 2 is: %p\n", &ball2);
    printf("Address of ball 2 in the array is: %p\n", &(ball1.adjacent[0]));

    // different but Ok as malloc has returned a pointer

    ball1.adjacent[0].n_adjacent = 10;   // Updating ball 2 's adjacents

    printf("Adjacent of original ball 2 is: %d\n", ball2.n_adjacent); // prints 0
    printf("Adjacent of ball 2 in the array is: %d\n", (ball1.adjacent[0]).n_adjacent); // prints 10
```

1. - Arent ball2 and ball1.adjacent[0] the same ball (ball2)?
2. - Why did not the value of the ball2 get updated?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre], which includes the struct definitions and a definition of  `int main(void)`. Make sure it compiles and include the output in your question.

Comment: Do not use `[0]` dereference a pointer, this dose not well tell what you are doing. Just use `*` (so if you have `type* var` you can derefercen it with `*var`)

Answer (score 1):

> Arent ball2 and ball1.adjacent[0] the same ball (ball2)?

No. You make a copy of `ball2` and store it in `ball1_adj[0]` Then you assign the address of that copy to `ball1.adjacent`

> Why did not the value of the ball2 get updated?

Because modifying a copy doesn't affect the source of that copy. Just as burning a photo of your car doesn't damage your car.

If you want to modify other structs using the `adjacent` pointer you need to assign the address of the other struct instead of a copy:

```
ball1.adjacent = ball1_adj;
=>  ball1.adjacent = &ball2;
```

Comment: How would I assign 3 balls?

Comment: With the given structure you cannot. You would need to replace the pointer with a an array of pointers.